# Getting error when using material 2 snackbar

Tags: angular-material2

Getting error when using material 2 snackbar

> No provider for OverlayPositionBuilder!

i have included

```
> import {MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig , Overlay , OverlayContainer, }
> from '@angular/material'; import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from
> "@angular2-material/core";
```

from which file i should include OverlayPositionBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/material";
```

In my IDE (WebStorm) OVERLAY_PROVIDERS appears as an option when typing within {}

[image]

I can't confirm that this correct as I don't know how to test it as yet.